# How do I extract a string within a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, substring, locate

I have a string value:

```
'{"CUSTOMER_TOPUP":{"bankname":"45","amount":"1000","depositreference":"REF1111"}}'
```

and would like to return the value:
REF1111

which is the last portion of my Json string.

Note that my string can have a different value. Eg:

```
'{"BILLPAYMENT":{"utility":"11","amount":"50","accountnumber":"123456"}}'
```

and I need to return the value string 123456

I am using strictly Mysql where I am creating my own function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JSON functions?

```
json_extract(
    '{"CUSTOMER_TOPUP":{"bankname":"45","amount":"1000","depositreference":"REF1111"}}',
    '$.CUSTOMER_TOPUP.depositreference'
)
```

Or, if you want to get rid of the double quotes that surround the resulting value:

```
json_unquote(json_extract(
    '{"CUSTOMER_TOPUP":{"bankname":"45","amount":"1000","depositreference":"REF1111"}}',
    '$.CUSTOMER_TOPUP.depositreference'
))
```

Comment: I don't know how to use a json function with MySQL :(

Comment: @MikeAyuso: just use the functions as I showed in my answer, what is the problem with it?

Comment: If I use a json_extract() in a select statement I get an error telling me that the function is not found.

Comment: @MikeAyuso: which version of MySQL are you running? JSON functions were added in 5.7.